# Extracting nested JSON using json_extract_array: getting null results on populated data fields?

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I am attempting to extract the following configuration data from this nested json file ([Image of JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33cES.png)), using this query:

```
SELECT 
  json_extract_scalar(f, '$.affiliationTypes') as affiliation_types
  , json_extract_scalar(f, '$.organizationTypes') as organization_types
  , json_extract_scalar(f, '$.verificationTypes') as verification_types
  , json_extract_scalar(f, '$.notifierIds') as notifier_ids
  , json_extract_scalar(f, '$.metadata') as metadata
  , json_extract_scalar(body, '$.accountId') as account_id
FROM `my database`
left join unnest(json_extract_array(body, '$.request.config')) as f
LIMIT 100;
```

but am getting null results for all of the selected config data. I've even filtered on accounts/requests where I know there is config data listed still nothing. Any ideas? (many of these fields have data I've just nulled them out for this post).

AS an example, I would like for the first select statement to output: STUDENT_PART_TIME, EMPLOYEE, FACULTY, VETERAN, STUDENT_FULL_TIME, ACTIVE_DUTY

For those who dont want to open image, this is the json chunk I'm interested in:

```
"body": {
    "accountId":""
    ,"activeAffiliationTypes":[]
    ,"affiliations":[]
    ,"aggregateState":"OPEN"
    ,"birthMonth":null
    ,"birthYear":null
    ,"customerFacingConclusiveVerificationType":null
    ,"customerFacingRequestedAffiliationType":""
    ,"dataSourceErrorCodes":null
    ,"dataSourceResponseHttpStatusCategory":"UNKNOWN"
    ,"dataSourceResponseHttpStatusCode":-1
    ,"emailDomain":null
    ,"errorCodes":[]
    ,"errors":[]
    ,"issuedRewards":[]
    ,"metadata":{}
    ,"request": {
        "accountId":""
        ,"active":false
        ,"assetMap":{}
        ,"config": {
            "affiliationTypes":["STUDENT_PART_TIME","EMPLOYEE","FACULTY","VETERAN","STUDENT_FULL_TIME","ACTIVE_DUTY"]
            ,"assetTypes":[]
            ,"consolationRewardIds":[]
            ,"ignoreVerifierClasses":null
            ,"locale":"en_US"
            ,"metadata":{}
            ,"notifierIds":null
            ,"organizationTypes":[]
            ,"rewardIds":[]
            ,"testMode":false
            ,"verificationModelClass":""
            ,"verificationSourceClasses":[]
            ,"verificationTypes":["AUTHORITATIVE"]
            }
        ,"created":null
```

Comment: This JSON file is only one of thousands I'm interested in, so it's just an example I want this query to search through every file.

Comment: You are trying to extract an array on "$.request.config" which is not an array. Try using JSON_EXTRAC() instead.

Comment: Hi thanks I figured it out. Something along those lines although I wanted the result as type string, so I performed query which I've posted as an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT      STRING(c)
FROM        'my database'
LEFT JOIN   UNNEST(
              JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(body, '$.request.config.affiliationTypes')
            ) c
```